# Request to a JSON returning URL via WebClient throws an exception

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, webclient

I am sending a request to Facebook Graph API by using WebClient with the following code that is written in an ASP.net MVC Controller class:

```
 WebClient client2 = new WebClient();

        Stream data2 = client2.OpenRead("https://graph.facebook.com/me&" + s);
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(data); //Error


        string s2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
        data2.Close();
        reader2.Close();

        s2=s2.Substring(s2.IndexOf('"', s2.IndexOf(':')), s2.Length - s2.IndexOf('"', s2.IndexOf(':')));

        s2= s2.Substring(1, s2.IndexOf('"', 1) - 1);

        return "AccessToken Stored in session, Current Signed in user is: "+s2;
```

I am getting this error: "System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable." at the line commented as //Error. This request to https://graph.facebook.com returns data in JSON format. Is that causing this exception? Please help. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be pointing out the obvious, but you are passing the "data" variable into the StreamReader constructor right after creating the "data2" variable.  I am guessing that you meant to pass in "data2" instead?

Comment: Oh such a silly mistake by me. Thanks for pointing out. This was exactly the problem. :$

Comment: No worries.  I have definitely made that same mistake as well.